# Can anyone guide me to use json with php and get output in android through an example?

Tags: php, android, json, eclipse

Here I have Php code :

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Cannot Connect to Server");
mysql_select_db("info") or die("Cannot Connect to Database");

$sql = "Select * from personal_info where Id=1 ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$no = mysql_num_rows($res);

if($no != 0){   
    print(json_encode($res));
}
else
{   
?>

    <script language="javascript">alert("False output");</script>

<?php
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Please let me tell how would I program my android to get output from this code.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: in android try to load json from php page URL...and then decode json in android app to show data....Simpleeeeeee.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fix for your current php code. Not an android code. Your current json code rewrriten as below.

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Cannot Connect to Server");
    mysql_select_db("info") or die("Cannot Connect to Database");       

    $sql = "Select * from personal_info where Id=1 ";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $no = mysql_num_rows($res);

    $jsonArray =array();
    $msg ="failed";
    if($no>0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

            $jsonArray[] = $row;
        }
        $msg ="success";
    }
    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$msg, 'data'=>$jsonArray));
```

Remove below lines from your code,

```
        if($no != 0){

            print(json_encode($res));
        }
        else
        {
            ?>

        <script language="javascript">alert("False output");</script>

        <?php
        }
```

Comment: is this code for android??? 
plz read question ....that already generate JSON...want to ger in android device

Comment: @Kuldeep Choudhary, Thanks to pointing out!. I have given the fixes for his php script!.